# Who is the first minority superhero in mainstream US superhero comics?

Tags: comics, history-of, super-hero, society

This came up after talking with a friend recently.  I commented that, with my relative lack of knowledge of comics, I didn't think I had seen any minority superheroes in comics until I saw the *Justice League* cartoon on Boomerang and realized they had a new Green Lantern (John Stewart).  My understanding is there are more minorities in comics than when I was growing up and got to read the odd comic book or two, but when I look at posters for DC and Marvel, most of the characters seem to still be Caucasian.

When and who was the first minority superhero in the two big comic lines (Marvel and DC) in the U.S.?

Note: My intent here was to look at larger US publishing groups, such as Marvel and DC, who were in a situation where they could, for years, publish stories about people within one group (in this case Caucasian and mostly males).  With that group in mind, my thought was, "When did they start to make changes and open up to different groups and move past designing all their characters to appeal to one group."  That's why I wasn't looking at independent publishers, or cases where a small publisher was publishing within a minority group.

Comment: In case you wonder, I deleted my answer because [John Steward](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Stewart_(comics)) is 4 years older than [Storm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storm_(Marvel_Comics)). However, seeing that Kal-El is (close to) the only living being of his species, he's the first minority super-hero :)

Comment: Interestingly, minority super-villains were depicted long before minority super-heroes: for example, the caricature villain "[Yellow Claw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_Claw)".

Comment: The question should state by which context we should consider the minority. Culture of primary intended story audience? Culture the character interacts most within canon? Culture of the author of story? Culture of the author of this question?

Comment: @IlariKajaste: That's true, but considering that I've essentially narrowed it down to DC and Marvel, that pretty much narrows down the culture.

Comment: @TangoOversway I'd be pretty sure that the "two big comic lines" are both Japanese. Marvel and DC are two medium-size comic lines that happen to be the largest in the US.

Comment: Kryptonian-Americans are not a minority??

Comment: The Martian Manhunter dates back to 1955, and he is a person of color (Green)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Edited to add in the correct info about the first minority super hero.

In DC Comics [*All-Star Western* #117](https://www.comics.org/issue/16083/) published in February 1961 the first Native American superhero appeared with the horrible name of Super-Chief.

[image: All-Star Western 117 cover; female gunner ripping the holster out of a male gunner's belt with a bullet]

A summary of his origin can be found here [The Crowning of Super-Chief.](http://thefifthbranch.com/gorilladaze/hail-to-the-super-chief-2/)  Super-Chief appeared in the next two issues and then the series was cancelled.

Marvel introduced the Black Panther in [*Fantastic Four* #52](https://www.comics.org/issue/20188/) in July of 1966.

[image: FF #52 cover, featuring Black Panther alongside the titular Fantastic Four]

However, it may not be accurate to say that the character is a minority.  The Black Panther is in reality T'Challa, King of the fictional African country of Wakanda.  Although he would be seen as a minority in the United States due to being African he is not part of the African-American minority in the US.

DC introduced its first minority superhero the Black Racer in June 1971 in [*New Gods* #3.](https://www.comics.org/issue/24280/)

[image: New Gods 3 cover; Black Racer poiting a gun at New God Orion]

The Black Racer may not really qualify as a superhero though.  The character is part of Jack Kirby's [*Fourth World* series.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_World_%28comics%29)  The corporeal form of the Black Racer is an African-American Vietnam veteran named Willie Walker.  When Darkseid brought the war of the New Gods of New Genesis and Apokolips to Earth the Source, a sort of God like universal shared consciousness, contacted Walker and turned him into the deity known as the Black Racer.  The Black Racer's job is to collect the souls of the New Gods when they die and deliver them to Hadis the Fourth World version of Hades.

So where does that leave us if we ignore these two entries.
Marvel's next African-American hero was the Falcon introduced in [*Captain America* #117](https://www.comics.org/issue/22963/) in September 1969.

[image: Captain America 117 featuring the superhero falcon and a litteral falcon]

The Falcon is the alter ego of Sam "Snap" Wilson.  He was trained by Captain America after he fought beside him against a group of former Nazis working with the Red Skull.  The Falcon did have one definite first in that the word 'Black" wasn't part of his superhero name.

DC's next black superhero appeared in [*Green Lantern* #87](https://www.comics.org/issue/24687/) published in December 1971.

[image: Green Lantern #87 cover, John Stewart holding a defeated Hal Jordan]

This is the previously noted John Stewart.  Artist Neal Adams resisted the powers that be who wanted to name the character Isaiah Washington.

However, all that being said these were not the first non-stereotyped or non-racist African-American characters in comics.  These were just the first superheroes.

Comment: Excellent answer: well-researched and covers not just the explicit question but the implicit questions as well as a historical analysis.

Comment: @MarkBeadles Unfortunately not researched quite enough.  Finally found the real first one.  I had to find a better description of his first story to make sure he was considered a superhero though.  Edited my answer to add it in.

Comment: @MajorStackings  That's why I said it "may not be accurate."  Some people are intent on arguing semantics today.  Personally, I agree with you that he should be considered a minority superhero.

Comment: @Legion600 Thanks again for doing further research to provide a serious answer.

Comment: @MarkBeadles  I'm an unemployed historian.  I have nothing better to do than look up insignificant trivia on the net.

Comment: Anybody noticed the interesting increase of the price/issue over the years? From 10c in 1961 to 25c in 1971.

Comment: @bitmask That issue of Green Lantern was a 48 page issue.  Issue #89 was 52 pages for 25 cents.  Issue #90 was 36 pages for 30 cents and by #95 it was 35 cents.  And now they are $2.99 and up.

Comment: And now I see why they have the Hal Jorden version of GL, not Jon Stewart. They'd have to have cast SL Jackson and he's tied up in marvel....

Comment: While not a "Super-Hero" per se, mention should be made of Dr. August Durant, a member of the Secret Six, which premiered in May, 1968.

Answer (score 17):

[Zorro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorro) was introduced in 1919 and is a Spanish hero. But I don't know if you could consider him a minority hero as he fought crime in a Spanish colony in California, so he would have been of the majority.

But the character was created by Johnston McCulley who was born in Illinois and was printed in the USA.

Comment: Zorro fought crime in the Spanish colony of California not Spain.  But you are right that he would have been in the majority.

Comment: What label was Zorro published under?  Was it a major one?

Comment: It was Disney's comic publisher

Answer (score 13):

Honorable mention to [Luke Cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luke_Cage), aka Power Man (of [*Power Man/Iron Fist*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_Man_and_Iron_Fist) fame), since I believe he is the first with his own eponymous title.

First appearance - 1972.

Answer (score 11):

Marvel introduced the Black Panther in 1966. The Black Panther, one of the Avengers, was originaly from Wakanda Africa. He visited America and lived there for a time where he used the secret identity of Luke Charles, an American teacher.

Comment: Sounds like a winner to me: "*He is the first black superhero in mainstream American comics*" [(Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Panther_(comics)).

Comment: I think this is correct, insofar as the Black Panther was the first serious, non-stereotyped, superhero depicted as a racial minority.

Comment: The Black Panther's not in a minority; he comes from Wakanda, an African country where he's part of the majority ethnic group.

Comment: So, we are saying the only racial minority that can be considered for this question are african americans?

Comment: @OghmaOsiris No, but we are saying that the first minority superheroes were African-American.

Comment: @Mike Scott Edited my answer to address your concern.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris I was wrong.  The first was Native American.

Answer (score 9):

Tarzan, I should think. Since he spends all his time in Africa, he's definitely in an ethnic minority group.

Comment: He's not a superhero though.

Comment: He's also the quintessential Great White Male that rules over all the lesser beings in the jungle. He's not a minority, he's a racist stereotype we generally overlook because the story is considered a classic.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to throw Lee Falks Phantom into the mix. [The Phantom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Phantom) began as a daily comic strip in 1936 (at that time he was the 20th Phantom, the first Phantom took on the role in the 1500's) and he became a world renown fictional hero. He was the first to wear a skin tight outfit as well as a mask without visible pupils. The location of his base of operations (Skull Cave) varied as time passed from Asia to Africa.

Through the 1940s, strips were reprinted in Ace Comics.

The Phantom was later published by Harvey Comics in the '50's, followed by Gold Key Comics, King Comics and Charlton Comics. Marvel Comics published a 4 issue miniseries in 1987. DC Comics took over in 1988.

Moonstone books began publishing graphic novels in 2002. Check out Legion600's answer to my question [Which world-renowned fictional hero was the first to wear a skintight costume and a mask with no visible pupils?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/11954).

Comment: Can you add more context?  What year was he introduced, what makes him notable, etc?

Comment: The Phantom began in newspaper strips.  He wasn't published by either of the big two publishers until 1988.

Comment: @Keen- Sorry, got pulled away from the keyboard. Edited as requested.