# Which world-renowned fictional hero was the first to wear a skintight costume and a mask with no visible pupils?

Tags: history-of, character-identification, costume

It had to start somewhere. Which world-renowned fictional hero is credited as being the first to wear a skintight costume and a mask with no visible pupils?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It appears that the first hero to fit your description would be [The Phantom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Phantom) who first appeared in newspaper strips on February 17, 1936.

[image: Phantom 2-24-36]

We have both the skintight costume and the mask with no visible pupils.

The Phantom has been published in comic book form in the United States, Sweden Finland, Norway, England, Mexico, Israel, Spain, Poland, Russia, Denmark, Hungary, Germany, Turkey, New Zealand, Australia, Turkey, Iceland, South America, France, Thailand, Singapore, Netherlands, Chile, Greece, Yugoslavia, Fiji, Venezuela, and Italy so I think that gives him the world renown status you were also looking for.

There is a really good story about the origin of the character at [Comicology.](http://www.comicology.in/2009/04/lee-falks-phantom-1-origins-of-ghost.html)