# Who was the first African/Black superhero?

Tags: history-of, super-hero

While reading an article on Marvel's [Luke Cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luke_Cage), it mentioned a few other black superheroes, but I didn't see a couple that probably opened the doors to such a thing. I then looked up who I thought was the first African superhero - [**Lothar**](http://www.comicvine.com/lothar/4005-61659/) (of [Mandrake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandrake_the_Magician) fame) - but apparently he wasn't the first.

**Who was the first African/Black superhero (defined here as a protagonist having powers or abilities beyond normal men)?**

For this question, let's limit ourselves to modern media - pulp magazines, comics, film/tv, novels, etc. No folklore, mythology, or tribal legends.

Comment: Are you talking comic books, films, TV shows, folklore etc?

Comment: @DrRDizzle - added to question. We'd probably find a lot of supernatural abilities if we included folklore & oral tradition, so let's stick with modern superhero media.

Comment: [Novels about folklore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Henry_(novel))?

Comment: @JasonBaker - nah. And honestly, I don't know if John Henry would even count. In most versions of the story, he isn't superhumanly strong or anything, he's just very strong and a hard worker. That particular story has been embellished quite a bit over the years.

Comment: Related/dupey: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/11927/1027

Comment: @Keen - Dupish, but not a dupe. The other question is asking about mainstream comics (DC/Marvel) only.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### First black comic-book main character

This honour goes to "Lion Man", who debuted in 1945 as the hero of the groundbreaking one-shot "[All Negro Comics #1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-Negro_Comics)". While he doesn't have any discernible 'lion powers' he does seem to have exceptional agility, hearing and aggression. He's heroic, but not **super**heroic.

[image]

### First (regular) black character in a superheroic comic

This honour goes to [Gabriel "Gabe" Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabe_Jones), debuted in 1963 as one of the Howling Commandoes. Although he doesn't have any obvious superpowers, it's notable that he doesn't age, something that has been commented upon in-universe (with regard to Nick Fury).

[image]

### First Black title superhero with powers

This would probably be [T'Challa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Panther_(comics)), otherwise known as the Black Panther, who debuted in 1966 in Fantastic Four #52.

His powers include...

> ...superhumanly acute senses and increases his strength, speed, stamina,
>   reflexes, and agility to Olympic-levels. He has since lost this
>   connection and forged a new one with another unknown Panther deity,
>   granting him augmented physical attributes as well as a resistance to
>   magic.[61] His senses are so powerful that he can pick up a prey's
>   scent and memorize tens of thousands of individual ones. Following his
>   war with Doom, T'Challa loses his enhanced abilities only to once
>   again establish a connection with the Panther God.

[image]

*which leads us to the...*

### First Superheroic black character

As pointed out by Omegacron in his comment below, the first superheroically powered black character is "[Lothar](http://www.mandrakewiki.org/index.php?title=Lothar)", Mandrake the Magician's sidekick who briefly debuts in the [first Mandrake story](http://www.mandrakewiki.org/index.php?title=The_Cobra_(Daily_story_1934)) in 1934. Lothar is described as the "Strongest Man in the World" and on at least one occasion lifts an elephant into the air, a feat that goes well beyond normal human abilities.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Lothar first appeared in 1934, so he predates all of these. And he could pick up an elephant, was invulnerable to weapons, and had the stamina of ten men. I'm not sure why the article said he was "one of the first" - it seems like he was probably THE first. I mean, if Richard can't find it, it ain't out there.

Comment: @Omegacron - Excellent point, well made. I spotted that he was the world's strongest man but didn't spot that his powers actually went well beyond human-max

Comment: Gabriel Jones is as white as a ghost covered in mayonnaise during a blizzard in that picture.

Comment: @DrRDizzle - Blame the colourist

Comment: A truly Thaddeusian answer!

Comment: I feel obliged to point out at this point that Lothar looks like an angered tomato covered in ketchup.

Comment: @Richard - Blame the printers, who were limited to more than 5-6 colors per page at the time, which explains both Gabe and Lothar.  What I don't understand is why they didn't use that orange-brown color for Lothar instead of tomato-red?  They'd have to pick another color for his shirt, but that seems like it'd be less of an issue...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - that's a good question, but it would probably merit a whole separate post/question of its own. I'd also be curious to see what difference there is - if any - between the original color on paper vs. paper that's been in storage for decades, then scanned in. Unfortunately, we have no way of knowing without exactly replicating the precise combination of press, ink, and paper from that time.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - Per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabe_Jones#Publication_history); "*Although colorist Stan Goldberg knew that Jones was African American, the company that made the engraving plates for Sgt. Fury and his Howling Commandos #1 thought a mistake had been made and colored him the same color as the rest of the Howling Commandos."*

Comment: Related Article: http://marvel.com/news/comics/15240/a_marvel_black_history_lesson_pt_1#ixzz1QFnuw5Yi. Points out that Falcon was the first African-*American* superhero, as opposed to Black Panther, who is not American.

Comment: @DCShannon - I considered mentioning Falcon, but since the question doesn't ask about African-America heroes, I decided against it.

Comment: @Valorum Understandable. I was previously under the impression that Falcon was the answer to this question, so him not being mentioned in the body led to me doing additional research to figure out why.