# African superheroes created by African writers?

Tags: comics, super-hero

Are there any African superheroes created by writers native to Africa? It just stands to reason that there has to be at least 1 superhero that’s native to the African continent. I just want to be sure myself.

Comment: That sounds a bit broad. The usual tweak for that is asking which one was the first (like [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/104732/98028) which was about the first African/Black superhero, regardless of the writer)

Comment: Does the writer have to be actually born in Africa to count, or does it count if they are of African descent?

Comment: The writer actually has to be born in Africa & the superhero has to be native to Africa as well.

Comment: It is a bit broad. On the other hand, it's interesting.

Comment: @Adamant The original version of the question is an "any" question, which is not really a list question and is [on-topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1490/31936). No edit was necessary.

Comment: @Null - I'm sorry, I'd forgotten that policy. Well, the date information won't hurt.

Comment: @Adamant No worries. The date information won't hurt but asking for "any" superhero (as the OP intended) rather than only the "first of" means that none of the existing answers are invalidated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Captain South Africa and Razorman](https://www.iol.co.za/news/south-africa/gauteng/meet-captain-south-africa-the-superhero-who-doesnt-want-to-punch-criminals-17125836) are both creations of Zimbabwean author [Bill Masuku.](https://www.billmasuku.com/rm/)

His blog has links to other African authors.

Comment: *Masuku's Captain South Africa, a black female superhero who "doesn't want to punch criminals because that doesn't end crime"* this is pretty great!

Answer (score 9):

There's a whole [Egyptian superhero universe](http://www.gizmodo.co.uk/2018/08/your-guide-to-the-egyptian-superhero-universe-of-el3osba/), with Egyptian superheroes written by Egyptians. (Egypt is of course in Africa.)

This universe debuted in 2012.

Comment: Was it 2012? I see 2015? https://deskgram.net/explore/tags/egyptiansuperheroes

Comment: @Adamant _"Since it debuted in 2012 as a series of short stories by John Maher on Facebook, the reaction to El3osba has been overwhelmingly positive at home and abroad."_ - From the link in the answer

Comment: Ah, OK. Cool, I guess 2015 was the publication of the first print volume.

Answer (score 3):

There's several South Africa based superheros in the *Kwezi* comic book, including the titular [Kwezi, Azania and Khoi](https://mg.co.za/article/2018-02-22-the-best-of-who-we-are-sa-comic-book-brings-new-superheros-to-the-scene). The writer is Loyiso Mkize, [also from South Africa](https://www.bbc.com/news/av/world-africa-36772788/meet-kwezi-africa-s-cartoon-superhero).

Answer (score 1):

https://youneekstudios.com/exo/  Here's a comic company founded by a Nigerian author, with African characters in Africa.